# Laravel Connection refused with different host name

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, mariadb, laravel-9

I am using a Laravel 9 installation that is running perfectly on localhost.

When I add `127.0.0.1 myapp.local` to my `/etc/hosts` (MacOS), I get a

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I am using MariaDB in a docker container together with nginx, where I added I vhost for `myapp.local`. When I don't use a mysql connection, Laravel is working.

My `.env` file has `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` and I tried `localhost`, `0.0.0.0`, `myapp.local` as well with the same error message.

The `DB_USERNAME` has access to `%` host.

Comment: Your laravel is runing inside container too? If yes, to try ping or telnet from laravel container to mysql for check connection between services

Comment: no it's not. It's just mapped as a volume to nginx

Comment: Is MySQL port open from your application host?

Comment: Yes. In the meantime I figured out, when I use the docker container_name as `DB_HOST` it is working and I can access the API through the browser but then I get the same error when I use php artisan db and this is only working when I swtich it back to 127.0.0.1 and then the browser does not work anymore

Comment: Good question so. Just to confirm, can you run something like `php artisan optimize:clear` to see if not is some cache on commands?
Make the correct DB_HOST to working with API on the browser, and run optimize before to try run command...

Comment: Additional question: You has some `Model` called by your db command with custom `connection`? Or is all default?

Comment: I use the default config

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I needed to use the docker container name as host name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).